# The group of Carpenters or the group of Programmers?

Tags: technological-development

An elite life form is playing with the humans from the 2015s. They selected the best 100 carpenters and the best 100 programmers from the earth and teleported each group to their synthetic-earth planets(1 group, 1 planet). Despite of their current knowledge, both groups would have to start from scratch. Both groups were instructed to be able to build the world as close as where they came from.

Notes:

- Please elaborate the answer as far as their progress goes at least every 500 years.
- One might argue that an engineer for a space station is one of the best carpenters, but this question only classifies a carpenter/programmer to his qualification. The said engineer is overqualified to be a carpenter for this specific question and cannot be classified as carpenter.
- In no way does this skeptic question wants to raise a discrimination against jobs in case it raises one

Main Questions:

1. Who would most likely win this race?
2. Can the number of people affect this race? (i.e, maybe 100 carpenters wins against 100 programmers, but 200 programmers wins against 200 carpenters)

Comment: From the answers so far, there doesn't seem to be a clear answer to this.

Comment: Is there more than one 2015?

Comment: I feel like the answer of who would win is pretty obvious...the what would happen every 500 years is complete opinion though.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding! As it stands this is a very broad question. Would you consider narrowing it down?

Comment: This is a little silly, since without their tools neither side can use their professions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall, I would bet on the programmers. As a rule, programmers are significantly more intelligence than the average person, and the task will require either group to re-invent virtually the entire technological environment from scratch. Perhaps some of the programmers are members of the society for creative anachronism and have useful skills like smithing or basic agriculture. You have a potentially huge possible variation in initial skills. At best, you have a probabilistic answer.

Neither the programmers nor the carpenters will have the practical or theoretical knowledge to reboot a high-tech civilization in a generation or two, so their progeny will have to do all the heavy intellectual lifting.

Because you have such a small population basis, it will take around 15-20 generations to get the population basis high enough to support enough specialization to reboot. So, an overall boost in average intelligence would be the dominant advantage. Note that only a relatively small percentage of the population will be the scientist and engineers in either case as most of the people will be farmers, merchants, etc. but an scientist with 150 IQ can be significantly more productive that 130 IQ, so having the higher average population will result in more geniuses.

Either initial groups should be intelligent and educated enough to prioritize basic knowledge that needs to be preserved, e.g., literacy, basic math, basic hygiene and agriculture, etc. But there will only be so much the first generation can accomplish.

If your initial numbers was dramatically larger, you could eliminate some problems as well as the time needed to have a sufficiently large population -- but the much larger initial skillset would also change the dynamics of a reboot assuming the initial generation had time to record their skills for the future. Potentially shortening the reboot to a few generation given a sufficiently large population. With a large initial population, there would be less difference between the two groups.

Once you reach the industrial revolution stage, the remaining progress to a technological society should be more rapid than our own history. The ancient documents would give confidence that the things like semi-conductors and other high-tech goodies are there to be found and there would be lots of motivation to so do. 200 years ago our scientific knowledge was negligible compared to today. The reboot should go at least as fast.

I assume that the first generation has enough free-time to at least plan for the future. If you have hunting and fishing to supplement your food supplies and the new world is rich in such -- there will be such time. If not, you set back the progress of both groups by quite a bit as there is no time to help future generations progress. In a harsh world, both groups are in real trouble initially, but intelligence would still long term, assuming you don't wipe everyone out initially.

Programmers might have another initial advantage. They are simply more likely to be avid readers and be wealthier. They have a least a better chance of having some additional skills / knowledge because of their more varied hobbies and reading interests.

---

Programming is not just another skill, nor is physician, engineer, lawyer, etc. Yes, a person of average intelligence can become any of these, but in actual fact these occupations are among those are attract  [higher than average intelligence](http://www.randalolson.com/2014/06/25/average-iq-of-students-by-college-major-and-gender-ratio/). Certainly IQ is only 1 component and often overrated. But, programming is primarily an intellectual process. The 100 best in the world are almost certainly mostly geniuses or nearly geniuses. The best programmers I know are all very intelligent (I've been a developer for 30+ years).

The average carpenter has a lower than average IQ. Why is this so? Highly intelligent people have more career opportunities for higher paying jobs, so they become doctors, engineers, etc. The top 100 carpenters are also likely to be a good bit smarter than the average person -- but other things like hand-eye coordination, visual acuity, physical strength are also factors.

---

Several comments really miss the point. I am not saying programmers are practical, etc. I am saying they are more intelligent than average and especially the truly top programmers. Their offspring will be more intelligent on the average and more likely to reboot technological civilization more quickly. Programming is a very low priority as a reboot skill, but intelligence is not. Intelligence is not just in the genes, but it is an important component. Clearly there are smart carpenters and not very bright programmers, but whether we are only considering the top 100 in their field, or averages in their field, programmers will be more intelligent as will their progeny of 15 generations down the road.

Comment: Programmers aren't "significantly more intelligent than the modern person." They learned a valuable skill, the same way the average person learns to drive or ride a bike: lots of practice!

Comment: @DJM is right... I know a few really smart carpenters and a lot of below-average programmers.  As a programmer myself, I know how easy it is to be fooled by such a personal bias.  (As a side note, even if programmers are "more intelligence" on average, they are certainly 'less communication' too, and social skills are survival skills in a small group.)

Comment: Programmers usually are usually much less practical, the things they do work in *highly* structured environments and no where else. I have a minor in CS from my undergrad, but I'd still bet on the carpenters.

Answer (score 9):

## Both groups would die

The odds that a group of 100 effectively random modern-day people with no skills related to bare-bones survival would live long enough to even have time to start building *anything* representing a civilization is quite small.

You'll simply be missing out on a lot of skills that you need to *survive* the extremely harsh conditions of a non-civilized world that your groups will have better things to do then rebuild the modern world.

If they even manage to keep on their feet, it'll take them *generations* before they get to the point where there's enough time left over to start teaching their young things that aren't directly related to not dying the coming winter. By then, the original group will be long dead and whatever they once knew has become entirely irrelevant.

They will also run into considerable genetic issues; you need way more than a hundred people to have a viable gene pool and odds are good that if you select all of them by a common trait that many of them also share certain genes which only complicates things further. This won't impact things much the first few generations, but if you come back after 500 years it's probably become noticable already.

Comment: It does somewhat depend on where they get dropped. 

Somewhere that's fairly warm year round with significant food and clean water: both groups could make a decent go of things without too many dying immediately.  Drop them somewhere harsh and they'll all be dead pretty fast.

Comment: According to [this](http://www.newscientist.com/article/dn1936-magic-number-for-space-pioneers-calculated.html#.VVCmq3VieV4) the minimum viable population number for long term human survival is as low as 160, but that requires extremely specific skill sets plus equipment and infrastructure that definitely isn't part of the original setup.

Comment: @Murphy: any place with significant food and water also has significant competition already living there to contend with; both predators and other (bigger) hungry herbivores. It's mostly the difference between dying from the environment vs being killed by other creatures. I don't think they'd last significantly longer in a jungle than on a tundra.

Comment: @Erik Not always. Some environments are a lot less hostile to humans than others. On some islands there are "naive" species of animals on islands which lack large predators with no significant tendency to flee from humans. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_tameness I'd rate someones chances on a smallish tropical island with edible animals which don't run from them far far higher than their chances on a tundra where they're going to freeze to death if they don't find shelter within hours.

Comment: I think that such a starting position would be important to stress in the opening question, as they are very rare and the odds of landing there randomly are very small. That'd require really stacking the deck in favor of each group, but that doesn't seem to be the intention of the question as it stands.

Comment: Give each group ten tribal teachers to get them started on survival in the wild :)

Comment: Minimum viable populations are often stated as > 100, yet scientists also say that all humans are descended from a single person (aka mitochondrial Eve). Both statements cannot be true simultaneously.

Comment: That's not how "mitochondrial Eve" or "minimum viable populations" work, but explaining further is a bit beyond the available space in a comment box.

Answer (score 2):

### Carpenters

The result of "build the world as close as where they came from" in this situation (within the lifetime of those 100 people) will mean an effective technological level of late stone age, with the main technological challenges being development of agriculture, pottery and simple non-metal tools. They *might* make the transition to metal tools in their lifetime depending on their geographical location, availability of food, availability of raw materials (statistically neither group will have someone with decent geology survey practical skills) and their survival situation (shelter, animals, diseases), but that's not guaranteed IMHO.

Carpenters will have a clear advantage in this situation, as simple woodworking will be a major industry for buildings and implements. Any possible advantage of the programmer community will be lost since it could be relevant only many, many generations after all of them would be dead, and when writing down their knowledge for future generations, their "general tech background" knowledge should be prioritized (metallurgy, chemistry, geology, physics) instead of any computer-related information.

Comment: With what tools would the carpenters commence their work? "Start from scratch" means, they don't get to take their tools. Probably not even clothing.

Comment: As the 'late stone age' with 'simple non-metal tools' implies, they would start from stones, sticks and fiber/leather strands. A sharp stone is a very poor approximation of a proper axe, the same with rope-stick drills and saws made from animal jawbones, but in general such tools (and making of them) is closer to carpenter expertise than any other current profession except experimental/reconstructive archeology.

Answer (score -3):

The programmers would survive, the carpenters would properly not.

Everyone knows that Programmers are geeks, and scouts are geeks. The chances are that some of the geeks are overlapping, so the programmers with scout skills have a basic understanding of survival.

Also there is a chance that the programmers have played a lot of games involving planning some kind of resource collection and construction game that gives them an advantage in the planning of the first stages. Even though resource collection would take longer time in the real world than computer games.

Along with nature knowledge, the programmers have played Sim Farm or Farmer Simulator 2015. Giving them a good knowledge about plants, planting and harvesting seasons and roughly how much planting area that is needed to feed the population.

When the basic setup has been done the programmers who are most likely to have an electronics degree also know how to transform potatoes in to batteries and make primitive windmills, lightbulps and heating from basic materials.

They are also able to mathematically grasp the concept of calculating architecture and areas of living space along with strength of the building.

All this while the carpenters are trying to figure out where to get screws, screwdrivers, metal beams and plasterboard.

This answer is maybe not the most serious one but in all aspects never underestimate a programmer just because he or she most of the time writes code on a computer.

Comment: Game experience rarely translates well to real-world applications. You can get a good sense for logistics, but games ignore the time and effort that actually go into acquiring resources and getting them to a useable point.

Comment: @Frostfyre I didn't write they would be experts, just that they would have an idea of how to plan a start up. If you read the question you would see it was the top 100 programmers. I logically assumed they would not be idiots.

Comment: @MagicMouse and Illogically you assumed they would be able to outcompete a group of people with real-world experience in a craft (carpenters) that can significantly impact survivability. The way I see it the programmers will be busy trying to get a fire going and the **carpenters** will build a town.

Comment: @DJMethaneMan exaggeration promotes understanding, people are automatically assuming the programmers are muscle-less dimwits with no real world experience. I bet i as programmer can start a fire, build a primitive house and get a basic electronic setup before any carpenter can. Most carpenters today dont even know how wood looks like they work with aluminium beams and plasteroboards

Comment: @MagicMouse No, I don't assume that programmers are "muscle-less dimwits". I am stating that a Carpenter will have a way better idea of how to build a more stable shelter than a programmer.  I code in JavaScript and Java in my free time and I have muscles and I am certainly not a dimwit. It would take generations before re-building modern technology was possible (we need to mine the minerals) and by the time it is the knowledge of the programmers will have probably disappeared.

Comment: @DJMethaneMan i did say people - not you. And just because you write javascript in your sparetime i wouldnt align you with the top 100 programmers. (I dont even count me as the top 100 programmers, and i do alot more than write javascript in my sparetime.)

Comment: @Magic-Mouse I wouldn't count myself in the top 10,000. The point is that even if a programmer has the knowledge to get basic electronics, chances are the carpenters will out compete them.

Comment: @DJMethaneMan you still fail to explain how ? You are just saying they are going to win but now how? There is now power-tools for the carpenters, no plasterboard, no screws, no putty. They need to chop the woods with stone axes, they need to split the wood trunks, with no tools. Carpenters today is as much dependent on tech as computer users is. And as much in the dark when considering starting from zero. How would the Carpenters create electronic drills? Massive saw blades ?

Comment: @Magic-Mouse My logic is that, generally (but not all the time) carpenters are more fit or do more physical labor than the programmer. Once the carpenters figure out how to cut the wood (as you said, probably stone axes) they would have an edge on the Programmers who would have to learn wood working from scratch.

Comment: @DJMethaneMan No. Since carpenters today are doing most work with machines. Manual labour does not exists because health laws even dictates they cannot even lift their toolbox because they might hurt their backs. You still didnt explain to me how they would invent the powertools ?

Comment: @Magic-Mouse If they have a stone axe and obsidian blades (as the tech level would be in the beginning) they don't really need power tools. I know plenty of carpenters that use manual labor.

Comment: @DJMethaneMan Quote from question " Both groups were instructed to be able to build the world as close as where they came from"  < = the world they came from has powertools and cars. The question wasn't regarding who can build the first house. But who can build a world as close to the one they came from in leaps of 500 years.