# Which Profession will be the fastest to build the world?

Tags: technological-development

Which group of people belonging in the same Job/Profession will most likely be the fastest to rebuild the 2015 technological level and in how many years will they be able to reach it?

Details:

- The group of people would be 1500 individuals having the same profession, and is also perfectly eligible for this Minimum Viable Population(e.g., survival, fertility, genes).
- Professions you may select are only from the stone age up to the current for example, Feudal Japan Ninja or Bartender(implying Modern Bartender). Professions cannot be as abstract as (Doctor or Engineer). In this case, a (Psychiatrist or Aerospace Engineer) will suffice. If in case you cannot specify the profession anymore (Farmer, Pirate), at least add a description to help paint the picture(Agriculture Farmer/Agriculturist, Pirate like from the "Pirates of the Caribbean").
- The age of the planet(Earth) and it's organisms is set to 2015 but, the human infrastructure is of course not there so they have to build from nothing but the environment. This means they are already immune to viruses that killed our ancestors, or it's just that the past viruses no longer exists. Current viruses, like Ebola still exists but lets assume the starting survivors are perfectly healthy and in their best conditions(required to be MVP candidate).
- The starting position is a grassland near a good water supply, mountains and plains. They might start noticing predators(snakes, lion) soon after, but lets assume this position is not the nest, or currently a marked home for a certain predator.
- These individuals doesn't know they are in a technology race. They will not posses any material during the start except a basic clothing(T-shirt, shorts and shoes). Refrain adding specific skill set to your individuals such as elementary school teachers who all have won an international cooking contest of exotic foods. If the skill set is present to the average people of that certain profession, then feel free to include them to their description.

Comment: I'd say it is almost irrelevant. Rebuilding is going to take so long that initial conditions won't have significant impact. Maybe some agriculture related profession might be good for early survival though.

Comment: the politicians they're the architect of the world(s) by passing bills, sometimes they will remove any worlds that they dislike through force lol

Comment: Worldbuilders would be the obvious answer. This is nearly [the same question you asked earlier](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/17033/3202), but its even broader, I've voted to close.

Comment: Is this a race?  Are different groups competing?  Do the competitors start naked, or do they get gear?  (SEAL may win simply because they get to land with all their gear, and that's all they really need)

Comment: @CortAmmon Thank you for always responding. I added a detail to address your questions

Comment: I'd go with "Stone-age level farmers". They are the only known group to have ever pulled it off.

Comment: If possible, can someone at least please edit the question to lessen its broadness, or indicate in which detail this questions falls short on.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a mono-type group identified by a profession will get very far.  I vote for "human being" to be the first.  True, it's technically available pre-stone age, but I think the need for diversification is strong enough to warrant bending your rule against that.  Given how little can really be kept in 1500 people's heads, I'd guess the only really useful thing we could bring along and make stick would be a system of writing, so 5000 years should be enough to rebuild our level of technology.

Choosing not to bend the rules, Survival Expert would be my next bet.  After the 3rd or 4th generation, any "technology" that could have been remembered will vanish, so the fastest way back to 2015 would be to just dig in and start making a real civilization again.

> "A human being should be able to change a diaper, plan an invasion,
>   butcher a hog, conn a ship, design a building, write a sonnet, balance
>   accounts, build a wall, set a bone, comfort the dying, take orders,
>   give orders, cooperate, act alone, solve equations, analyze a new
>   problem, pitch manure, program a computer, cook a tasty meal, fight
>   efficiently, die gallantly. Specialization is for insects." -- Robert
>   Heinlein, Time Enough for Love

Answer (score 0):

To quote "Ghost in the shell":

> If we all reacted the same way, we'd be predictable, and there's always more than one way to view a situation. What's true for the group is also true for the individual. It's simple: Overspecialize, and you breed in weakness. It's slow death.

A single group of people would have a hard time rebuilding something. There is two things you need to take in to consideration.

One is the economics guy who are performing archery in his spare-time, or the carpenter who does live reenactment in the weekends and are sewing his own clothes from leather. Or the Truck driver who grew up on a farm learning to take care of cattle and maybe even treat the leather after a visit to the butcher. People rarely only posses one or two skills.

The second is that in a "world reboot" the primary concern is rarely your skills, because in our modern day we are really dependable on machines and technology, and it is few farmers who don't take care of his field with computer aids and pesticides. Few carpenters who can make his own wood but picks it from the sawmill. Few teamsters who makes their own wagons. So the main skill needed is the ability to adapt in to your new environment.

This is what made roaches so extreme resilient, the ability to adapt in to new environments.

Comment: If we want to credit adaptability, that means we'll give another point to Survival Expert.

Comment: I don't think adaptability and survival experts are the same thing but i agree that some kind of Bear Grylls would have a significant better chance of surviving. But a chef, a CEO, and a journalist might have better adaptability than a survival expert in certain situations.

Comment: The problem with a survival expert is that they would lack the drive to make living easy for their children, since they can get by with primitive shelters and eating grubs.  The civilization needs to get to a stage where food is reliable for normal people, then improve tech so that there is free time to work on other improvements